# System database replication SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication, disaster-recovery

What is the best practice in handling DR replication of the system databases?

If the DR server/instance name is different than production is it possible to replicate the MASTER and MSDB databases over? Or would you need full instance replication at that point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replicate or mirror the system databases.

If you use clustering, your system databases live on a shared disk, so they can be brought up on your DR node as clustering provides resilience at the instance level.

Backing up the system databases on each server should be sufficient to recover that server in the event of a failure.